# axes and labeling not in plot white area

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to make a plot in a Colaboratory notebook. I am using following code:

```
# Plot data
rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.title("Charleston", size=24)
plt.xlabel("Year", size=20)
plt.ylabel("High Tide Floods (days/year)", size=20)
plt.plot(HTF_yr.index, HTF_yr.numdays, color='black',marker ='o')
plt.show()
```

Result (below) displays axes and labels in a grey area.  How do I include them in the white area, i.e. the figure itself?

[image]

Comment: try to add `facecolor='white'` in your `plt.figure` function

Comment: worked!  Thanks!